# logstash agent doesn't output anything in verbose mode

Tags: logstash

I may be being incredibly impatient, but I can't get logstash agent to output anything. I've tried:

```
logstash agent --verbose
```

...nothing...

```
logstash agent -f config.conf
```

...nothing...

```
logstash agent -f GIBBERISH_STRING
```

...nothing...

The only thing that does anything is:

```
logstash deps
Cannot install dependencies; missing logstash.gemspec. This 'deps' command only works from a logstash git clone.
```

All I want to do is verify my configuration file. From the logstash documentation, this should work:

```
logstash --configtest -f config.conf
```

But of course that returns nothing as well. I'm using a fresh download of logstash 1.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'm an idiot. Logstash takes ~6 seconds to startup. I was expecting some sort of immediate feedback when I gave it a malformed configuration file. I was killing the process after about two seconds.